# jQuery .ready() function runs before iframe is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a document with an `iframe` tag inside it.

I use `$(document).ready()` to do some operations after all the page and its frames is loaded, but unfortunately it runs before `iframe` is loaded completely.

For example imagine:

Main page:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('iframe').contents().find('button'));
  });
  function click() {
    console.log($('iframe').contents().find('button'));
  }
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
  <BUTTON ONCLICK="click();">Click me</BUTTON>
  <IFRAME SRC="x.html"></IFRAME>
</BODY>
```

x.html:

```
<BODY>
  <BUTTON>Button</BUTTON>
</BODY>
```

When I refresh the page, console logs an empty object, but when I click the button, console logs the button object.

Why `ready()` function runs before `iframe` is loaded? What is the reason?

P.S: I use Chrome as browser.

Comment: Well the line $(document).ready( callback ) does that.
Use window code. https://coderwall.com/p/_jothq/jquery-when-to-use-document-ready-and-when-window-load

Comment: This is by design. There are two documents; the outer one and the one in the iframe. You've attached the event handler to the outer one.

Comment: Thanks @Gent, but .load() functions needs `url` parameter and does't work as a callback function lonely. Instead  I used `.on('load', callback)` and runs properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want all DOM content load and then run your function, then use

   ```
   $(window).on('load',function(){
       //Write your code here.
   });
   ```
2. if you want to check if the iframe is loaded or not before running any function of yours, Try this

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var storeTimeInterval = setInterval(function(){
           if($('iframe').length > 0 ){
               //write your code here
               clearInterval(storeTimeInterval);
           }
       }, 100);
   });
   ```